# How can you set data type of #define to long double?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, long-double

I have a c-code where I define some variables for pre-processing using the `#define` command.

However, I think that there are ways to toggle between float and double data types by doing for example:

```
#define 1.0f     // float data type
```

or

```
#define 1.0     // double data type
```

Is there a way I can use it to set a variable of long double data types?

Comment: Insert `l` or `L` into the suffix `1.0lf` is a `long double` constant. This has nothing to do with `#define`; `1.0f`, `1.0`, and `1.0lf` are `float`, `double`, and `long double` constants when they appear in source code regardless of whether they arrived there directly or via macro replacement.

Comment: Neither of your examples are valid C.

Comment: What I think Scott is getting at is that the C preprocessor and C are essentially two unrelated languages. The C preprocessor just does naive string substitution with no knowledge of the C language. And C itself doesn't know or care about preprocessing that happens before it sees the code. `#define` is a syntax error to C, and `1.0L` has not meaning to the preprocessor.

Comment: Consider using variable `static long double your_variable = 1.0L;` instead of define.

Comment: Or `constexpr static long double your_variable = 1.0L` for bleeding edge [C23](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3018.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suffix the [float constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant#Suffixes) with `l` or `L` to give it type `long double`:

```
1.0L
```

Do note that float constants only have meaning to C. As far as the [preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) is concerned, that's just a string of four characters, no different from any other.

Answer (score 0):

`define` expects an identifier. Your code is not valid C code as you are using a constant literal in place of identifier; but to answer your question, if you want your floating-point literal to be of type long double, you can use the suffix `l` or capital: `L`:

```
void foo(long double x) { // ...}
```

- 

```
 foo(1.0L);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constexpr long double foo = 1.0; /* In C23  */
```

Is another cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Mixing `long double` and `double` in the same expression is still bad practice, just as mixing `double` and `float`.